# Android camera button

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am writing a simple android camera application (SDK version 7). Can I handle camera button like in native camera app, i.e. soft click - focus, and hard click - capture photo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that many android devices do not have physical camera button.  It is safer bet to allow the way for the users to use touch screen for both focusing and taking photo.

Anyway, since you mention native camera app, I assume you mean the official camera app. In that case, you can find the source code at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git

Comment: Thanks. I just add to my app to method onKeyDown this: Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown " + keyCode); and in log it looks like i need to catch in onKeyDown KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FOCUS, because i click only on camera button and actually was 2 events onKeyDown with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FOCUS and KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA